# Geofield map widget does no appear

Tags: entities, location

I have installed and enabled geofield and geofield map, when i am editing the fields for my content types I have no choice for geofield_map?

Comment: All you need to do is install the geoPHP module, which is required by geofield.

Comment: Your question seems like a variation of [How to implement georeferencing in Drupal?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/189611) ... Maybe you want to refine your question to explain what the difference is?